# How to stay on same place of a WEB page when clicking on Highchards legend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am a beginner in JavaScript and using the Highchard library....
For a personal project, I built a dynamic WEB page (with PHP) that generates several graphs under each other.

Except that when I click on a legend in the last graph in order to make a curve disappear, my page goes up and does not stay where it was.

I tried to insert anchors with the "#" tag in my HTML code and run the command "window.location.href = URL + "#anchorDEVICES";" in a plotOptions/events element, but the page does not load on the URL followed by the "#" anchor.

I tried another approach using the JavaScript command "window.scrollTo(0, 750)" in the same section, but my page still doesn't go down to the graph where I clicked.

Will anyone have any idea on the math method to use to avoid that the page goes up when you click on the legend of the last graph?

Thank you very much in advance,

Thierry

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

```
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          point: {
            events: {
              click: function () {
                location.href = this.options.url;
              }
            }
          },

          events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {         // Fonction pour faire revenir la page au niveau de l'ancre de ce graphique
              console.log("on a cliqué sur " + this.name + " (index du texte : " + this.index + ") du graphique SwapPage");

              var uri = location.href;
              console.log("URL = " + uri);
              var uriAll = uri.split('#');
              console.log("URL trouvée = " + uriAll[0] );
              //window.location.href = uriAll[0] + "#ancreDEVICES";
              window.scrollTo(0, 1500);
            }
          }

        }
      },
```

"window.scrollTo" or "window.location.href = uriAll[0]+'#ancreDEVICES'" do not put the page on the good graphic...
I would only find a solution in order to stay on the same place on the Web page when i click on a legend of an Highcharts graphic.

Comment: Hi @Tirguy, If i understand you correctly, you need to only remove this line of code: `window.scrollTo(0, 1500);` to stay on the same place.